# Twitter Follow us feature with the ShareKit in iOS

Tags: ios, twitter, sharekit

Now I got the Sharekit 2.0 for Facebook and twitter features.

I could share text (facebook and twitter) with the SharKit 2.0.

But I don't know how to implement the "follow us" feature in the twitter.

I found the "SHKTwitter" class's "followMe" function, but I haven't amy references about it.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

`- (void)followMe;`  method in `SHKTwitter` class can be used only when your app uses xAuth as authentification method with pre iOS5 Twitter. Some info about **xAuth** authentication method is in `DefaultSHKConfigurator.m` file.

The method by default not used for **OAuth** authentication method, which is what you do most probably use.

edit:

It might work also with **OAuth**, if you specify *twitterUsername* to follow in SHKConfigurator.m.

The method can be called after user authenticates, most conveniently during send - so to be able to call it you should subclass SHKTwitter and override send method to call also `[self followMe];`

I have not tried it myself, it is just an idea.

Maybe it would be worth implementing it directly in ShareKit also for OAuth using sharer specific instruction...

Comment: then how can I implement the twitter follow us feature with the sharekit? Now I make an iOS5 app.

Comment: it might depend on the scenario - what is the reason for using follow me? In xAuth the user is presented a switch with the possibility to follow app/author. The same might be possible for OAuth, but it uses different sharing form than xAuth - the form would have to be refactored first. It is planned, but not that straightforward.

Comment: on iOS5app it might be easier - you might use twitter framework directly for follow me, without ShareKit.